# In airflow can end user pass parameters to keys which are associated with some specific dag

Tags: python, parameter-passing, airflow

i have searched many links but didn't find any solution to the problem i have. I have seen option to pass key/var into airflow UI ,but it is really confusing for end user to work as which key is associated with which dag. Is there any way to implement functionality like :

`While running an airflow job, end user will be asked for values to some parameters and after entering those details airflow will run the job`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to wait for user input let say in Airflow UI. DAG's are programmatically authored which means defined as a code and they should not be dynamic since they are imported in web server, scheduler and workers in same time and has to be same.

There are two workarounds I came up with, and we use first in production for a while.

1) Create a small wrapper around Variables. For each DAG then load Variables and compose arguments which are then passed into Operators via `default_arguments`.

2) Add Slack operator which can be programmatically configured to wait for user input. Afterwards, propagate that information via XCOM into next Operator.

Comment: how do you accomplish your 2nd workaround?